# Android Preference old and new value compare

Tags: android, preferences

I have got NewValue from activity1 and store on preference and compare with OldValue from activity2: my problem it dose not store oldValue..

on activity 1:

```
  int i = 5;      

  SharedPreferences prefs1 = getPreferences(0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
  editor.putInt("new", i);
  editor.commit();
```

on activity 2:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs1 = getPreferences(0);
    int oldValue = prefs1.getInt("old", 0);
    int newValue = prefs1.getInt("new", 0);

    /* Should Activity Check for Updates Now? */
    if (oldValue < newValue) {

        /* Save current newValue for next Check */
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
        editor.putInt("old", newValue);
        editor.commit();

        do something....

    }
```

Comment: this will probably not solve your problem but as a good practice you should use `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();` instead of calling `getPreferences()` again.

Comment: unfortunately it dosnt make any deference..

Comment: Like I said, it is just for good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want share preferences with activities then you need to use [getSharedPreferences(String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) but you are using [getSharedPreferences(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int))

> `getSharedPreferences(int)` 
> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for **accessing preferences that are private to this activity.** This simply calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

get `SharedPreference` object like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs1 =getSharedPreferences ("app_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

is the key of newValue  is "new" or "newValue" ? you saved it with key and retrieving with the other

So it won't find the newValue so it will be always equals zero

```
 editor.putInt("newValue", 5);
 int newValue = prefs1.getInt("new", 0);
```

So you newValue will equal 0 because no key "new" in prefrences

Comment: actually newValue = 5, if oldValue = 4 it should do something, then store newValue as a oldValue

Comment: editor.putInt("newValue", new);

 int newValue = prefs1.getInt("new", 0);

newValue = 0   because no key is "new" in prefrences